# Не работают карты Яндекс в android webView

Tags: javascript, android, yandex-maps-api, webview

Я делаю простое веб-приложение на андроид. На одной из страниц сайта, который используется в приложении есть встроенная Яндекс карта.
На устройствах с Андроид 4 и ниже, карта не отображается. Опытным путем выяснил, что не срабатывает событие `ymaps.ready`, в которое передается функция `init`, создающая экземпляр карты. Если вызвать функцию `init` по таймауту, то возникает ошибка

> "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

в строке

```
myMap = new ymaps.Map
```

то есть приложение не видит объект ymaps, хотя библиотека яндекс загружается. Пробовал загружать библиотеку яндекс на свой сервер - тот же результат. Все нужные разрешения в приложении выставлены. `setJavaScriptEnabled = true`. В андроид 6 и выше карты отображаются. В чем может быть дело?
Ниже код подключения карты:

```
var myMap;
// Дождёмся загрузки API и готовности DOM.
ymaps.ready(init);
setTimeout(init, 5000);
function init () {
    alert('init');
    // Создание экземпляра карты и его привязка к контейнеру с
    // заданным id ("map").
    myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        // При инициализации карты обязательно нужно указать
        // её центр и коэффициент масштабирования.
        center: [55.76, 37.64], // Москва
        zoom: 10
    }, {
        searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    });

    document.getElementById('destroyButton').onclick = function () {
        // Для уничтожения используется метод destroy.
        myMap.destroy();
    };

}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Примеры. Размещение карты на странице.</title>
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style>
        body, html {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 90%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<input type="button" id="destroyButton" value="Удалить карту"/>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Сам API-скрипт не отрабатывает из-за какой-то несовместимости. Для Андроид 4 и ниже попробуйте использовать другую версию API: `https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.oldie.1/?lang=ru-RU` или подобрать наиболее подходящую.

Comment: як варiант
https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы! подошел вариант, предложенный  woesss

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант обойти проблемы устареших встроенных браузеров, попробуйте заэмебедить Crosswalk, однако это сильно увеличит размер bundle - но гарантированно будет работать. См например тут https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android/embedding_crosswalk.html